# Plastic SCM comparison of two identical lines

Tags: comparison, diff, plasticscm

I have two lines that are identical but Plastic find them different. I have checked spaces, endlines and codification; I copy the left line and paste in the right file...and still finds these lines as not identical. What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Might be the change in timestamp, in that case you will have to uncheck the marked option in the screenshot below:

[image]